# PHP Multiple preg_replace functions in same instence

Tags: php

I currently have this code:

```php
    <h3><a href="<?php echo (isset($row_getDisplay['post_id']) ? $row_getDisplay['post_id'] : ''); ?>-<?php echo preg_replace('%[^-/+|\w ]%', '', ($row_getDisplay['title'])); ?>.html" ><?php echo (isset($row_getDisplay['title']) ? $row_getDisplay['title'] : ''); ?></a></h3>
```

Which outputs this:

> The Pirate Bay - AFK Documentary review

But, you can see it's a URL; I would like it to show up like this:

> the_pirate_bay_afk_documentary_review

I am completely confused about how to go about doing this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

do a second preg_replace:

```
 preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $url);
```

Then run it through:

```
 $url=strtolower($url);
```

then echo it.

Comment: you may not want the dash either?

Comment: replacing `\s` with `\W` probably would make sense

Comment: Where would I put the second preg_replace as I have been confused where to put a second one..
I also don't get the strtolower($url)
I just updated the original post with more code if that helps